# conectar sql server con php en mac

Tags: php, sql-server

Estoy tratando de conectar **sqlserver** con **php** en **mac** pero no logro conseguirlo.

Se supone que el siguiente código me debe arrojar conexión establecida pero no logro conseguirlo.

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.4.5";
$$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>'alumnos', 'UID'=>'sa', 'PWS'=>'root', 'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Ya agregaste los dll de las funciones sqlsrv() ? Y tambien los agregaste al php.ini?

Sin ninguno de estos pasos es imposible conectar a sql.

Comment: No es valida tu respuesta, debe ir en la sección de comentarios. Saludos.

Comment: Ya  lo resolví gracias por tu comentario